# Apply a function to three parallel array of arrays

Tags: arrays, pandas, python-2.7, enumerate

I have three arrays of arrays like this:

```
catLabels = [catA, catB, catC]

binaryLabels = [binA, binB, binC]

trueLabels = []
trueLabels.extend(repeat(y_true_categories, len(binaryLabels)))

def binaryConversion(trueLabel, evalLabel, binaryLabel):
    for true,eval, binary in zip(trueLabel, evalLabel, binaryLabel):
        if eval == true:
            binary.append(1)
        else:
            binary.append(0)

for x,y,z in zip(trueLabels,catLabels,binaryLabels):
    binaryConversion(x, y, z)
```

Each of the values in catLabels and binLabels is an array. `binLabels` contain an array of empty arrays, each of which I want to fill in 1s and 0s lets say for example `catA = [A B C A B D]` and `binA = []`. `trueLabels` contains multiple arrays each of which are the same (`y_true_categories`, i.e. my true categorical labels `[A C C B B D]`. In this case, my `binaryConversion` function should fill in `[1 0 1 0 1 1]` for the array `binA`.

For some reason my current function is not achieving this and leaves each of `bin A, binB, binC` empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the answer. The inner zip statement will not work because I start with empty binary labels, and zip only works when all the arrays you are zipping are of the same length. So I removed the `binaryLabel` from the zip function within `binaryConversion(trueLabel, evalLabel, binaryLabel)` and appended to each `binaryLabel` empty binary array inside the loop. In addition, I was appending 1s and 0s to the element-wise `binary`, instead of the actual empty array `binaryLabel`.

New code:

```
def binaryConversion(trueLabel, evalLabel, emptyBinaryArray):
    for true,eval in zip(trueLabel, evalLabel):
        if eval == true:
            emptyBinaryArray.append(1)
        else:
            emptyBinaryArray.append(0)

for trueLabels,predictionLabels,emptyBinaryArray in zip(trueLabels,catLabels,binaryLabels):
    binaryConversion(trueLabels, predictionLabels, emptyBinaryArray)
```